# Best way to do soap client request in ruby

Tags: ruby, soap, request

I'm using YieldManager Rightmedia, the API uses SOAP over HTTP to exchange requests and responses with its clients.How to build the web service client request using ruby.

**UPDATE**

```
  I follow as per the Yieldmanager docs.., I added the following

require "soap/wsdlDriver"

(soap_base, username, password) = ARGV
contact_client = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new(soap_base + 'contact.php?wsdl').create_rpc_driver
contact_client.wiredump_dev = STDOUT;
token = contact_client.login(username, password, nil)
```

when i trying to do this i got an connection refused error like `YieldManager: Connection refused - connect(2) (://:0)`

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [savon](https://github.com/savonrb/savon) library.

You install it with:

```
gem install savon --version '~> 2.0'
```

Then you create client:

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: "http://example.com?wsdl")
```

and then you send request:

```
response = client.call(:authenticate, message: { username: "luke", password: "secret" })
```

More info here: http://savonrb.com/version2